# Hide default menu items in wordpress apearance > menus

Tags: menus

In a wordpress theme, when i get to appearance > menus i can see some default options to add to my menu (pages, posts, custom-links,  etc) and custom post-types. I only need **Custom Links** to be shown. And I need it to come with the theme, so unchecking the boxes at "screen options" is not an option. I imagine there must be some code I need to add to the theme's functions.php. 
I was advised to try this:

```
add_filter( 'hidden_meta_boxes', 'custom_hidden_meta_boxes' );
function custom_hidden_meta_boxes( $hidden ) {
    $hidden[] = 'pages';
    return $hidden;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You will able to remove nav menu meta-box links from screen option but if you want to remove by custom code, please try below code, simply copy and paste this into your functions.php file:

```
function custom_remove_menu_link_types() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    foreach ($wp_meta_boxes['nav-menus']['side'] as $nav_menus) {
        foreach ($nav_menus as $nav_id => $nav_menu) {
            // remove all menu's and keep only one
            if ($nav_id !== 'add-custom-links') {
                remove_meta_box($nav_id, 'nav-menus', 'side');
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'custom_remove_menu_link_types', 10);
```